# Unable to get static assets in a rails app: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, static-files

I'm not able to get the different assets served in a [dockerized](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails) rails production environment (`RAILS_ENV=production`) on my local computer.

These files actually do exists in the public/assets/ folder.

The web site is accessible but as raw HTML, without CSS/JS, certainly because the following error is raised in the `production.log` file:

```bash
# cat log/production.log

I, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.165501 #41]  INFO -- : [ccfb6a0a-ebc7-4ab6-a933-1dddc89a89f9]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.8ms | Allocations: 1632)
I, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.165615 #41]  INFO -- : [ccfb6a0a-ebc7-4ab6-a933-1dddc89a89f9] Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms | Allocations: 6515)
I, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.231023 #41]  INFO -- : [7d618f53-18ac-4710-a379-6fc98fe3466f] Started GET "/assets/application-4f692451ca795361d6bc74672d177c323051f106ffcd83d32ff58f8254585b62.css" for 192.168.224.1 at 2023-02-27 21:55:10 +0000
F, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.231573 #41] FATAL -- : [7d618f53-18ac-4710-a379-6fc98fe3466f]   
[7d618f53-18ac-4710-a379-6fc98fe3466f] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-4f692451ca795361d6bc74672d177c323051f106ffcd83d32ff58f8254585b62.css"):
[7d618f53-18ac-4710-a379-6fc98fe3466f]   
I, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.232047 #41]  INFO -- : [fc6819d9-c76a-4e6d-b45b-a3d87ddb43c4] Started GET "/assets/application-87512282de282bb22c97cee429573ad6c033b822ab2a2f8fa5df2733f7ed8456.js" for 192.168.224.1 at 2023-02-27 21:55:10 +0000
F, [2023-02-27T21:55:10.232292 #41] FATAL -- : [fc6819d9-c76a-4e6d-b45b-a3d87ddb43c4]   
[fc6819d9-c76a-4e6d-b45b-a3d87ddb43c4] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-87512282de282bb22c97cee429573ad6c033b822ab2a2f8fa5df2733f7ed8456.js"):
[fc6819d9-c76a-4e6d-b45b-a3d87ddb43c4]
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:slim-bullseye

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get -y upgrade \
  && apt-get install -y \
     build-essential make gcc libpq5 libpq-dev nodejs npm \
  && npm install -g yarn \
  && bundler install \
  && yarn \
  && rails assets:precompile \
  && rails yarn:install \
  && ldconfig
```

the entrypoint of my Compose file:

```bash
set -e

rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid 

DB_INIT=0
if db_version=$(rails db:version 2>/dev/null)
then
    if [ "${db_version}" = "Current version: 0" ]
    then
        echo "DB is empty"
    else
        echo "DB exists"
        DB_INIT=1
    fi
    rails db:migrate 
else
    echo "DB does not exist"
    rails db:setup
fi

if [ ${DB_INIT} == 0 ]
then
    echo "First configuration of the database..."
    rails db:migrate
    rails db:seed
fi

rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Plus there are these two relevant variables in the `config/environment/production.rb` file:

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.compile = false
```

The closest topic I found is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639662/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-assets-rails-actiontex) but `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` is actually not set in my project.

What am I doing wrong? (please consider I've discovered ruby/rail a few hours ago in your answer)

Comment: If `config.public_file_server.enabled` is set to false rails won't serve static assets like it will in development. Instead you typically configure the HTTP server such as NGinX that to serve them directly. If you don't actually handle it at all and the request is going to go to your Rails server and it will treat it as if it were any other request and send the request to the Rails router. You don't want that as it results in the error you are getting here.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation